# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime for spanish region

Tags: c#, datetime

Following conversion work for `"en-US"` region but not for `"es-AR"` Spanish Argentina region. Please suggest where is I wrong!

```
 var cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Argentina Standard Time");
 var _result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.Parse("Mar  1 2015  1:00AM"), cstZone).ToString("MMM dd yyyy H:mm tt", new CultureInfo("es-AR"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified a `CultureInfo` for `DateTime.Parse` so it fails when the current culture is `es-AR`. The date that you have specified happens to parse with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` so you can fix your code by adding the necessary `CultureInfo`:

```
DateTime.Parse("Mar  1 2015  1:00AM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

However, you might want to use `DateTime.ParseExact` specifying both the expected format as well as a `CultureInfo` to not get any unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime.Parse` uses [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) settings *by default*.

That means your `CurrentCulture` doesn't have `MMM  d yyyy  h:mmtt` as a [standard date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

In such a case, your can *directly* specify your format with `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` methods with [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or an *english-based* culture because we need to parse `Mar` part and `AM` part as well.

```
string s = "Mar  1 2015  1:00AM";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "MMM  d yyyy  h:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    dt.Dump(); // 01.03.2015 01:00:00
}
```

Comment: I guess `H` in you string should be `h` if this is the 12-hour system (hour number in range 1-12 inclusively).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen But string has `AM` part, that doesn't make it in _24-hour_ format? Also using widest range issue?

Comment: So is e.g. `21:00AM` a valid time of day in you opinion. _Either_ you use an hour count in 0-23 and no AM/PM designator, _or_ you use an hour count in 1-12 and include the AM/PM mark. Any hybrid would be confusing.

Comment: Yes Soner...Thank you very much..i already had used tryParseExact but the format was wrong.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You are right, looks like _24-hour clock_ doesn't represent any time designator by default. [Wikipedia says this as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock). Sorry about that. Corrected my answer. Looks like I need to read that page one more time.